# character encoding for mixed data

Tags: php, encoding

I'm having an issue with getting the correct character encoding for data being `POST`ed which is built up from multiple sources (I get the data as a single POST variable). I think they're not in the same character encoding...

For instance, take the symbol **£**. If I do nothing to the character encoding I get two results:

a = **Â£** and b = **£**

I've tried using various configurations of `iconv()` like so;

```
$data = iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1252//TRANSLIT', $_POST['data']);
```

The above results in a = **£** and b = �

I've also tried `utf8_encode/decode` as well as `html_entity_decode`, as I think there's a possibility that one of the pound symbols are being generated using `html_entities`.

I've tried setting the character encoding in the header which didn't work. I just can't get both instances to work at the same time.

I'm not sure what to try next, any ideas?

Comment: How is the `$_POST` data made? Is it possible to include the encoding of each part?

Comment: The post data is all coming from a database and is then collated into a single variable. This could technically be rewritten to set the encoding right for each part - however that's a far bigger task than I'd like. If it has to be done, it has to be done, but hopefully that's avoidable.

Comment: what is the database tables encoding?

Comment: There are quite a lot of tables, some are `utf8_general_ci` others are `latin1_swedish_ci`

Comment: I'd suggest you read [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/) and [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/) in addition to the linked duplicate. You really do not want to have to deal with converting encodings at all in your system.

Comment: Thanks for the links, I'll have a read. Just to note; the fact this data is not in a uniform encoding is unfortunately an inherited problem, not one I caused myself. I'm fully aware of the problems that can arise due to this ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to work around this issue by finding the content that was causing an issue when everything else was in `utf8` by using `utf8_encode()`.

This appears to work for the £ symbol. I've not found any other characters causing an issue so far.

Note, I am still using `iconv()` in conjunction with this.